# Tensorflow conv3d_transpose (upsampling) fully connected layer

Tags: tensorflow, convolution, deconvolution

I want to mimic [this](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Long_Fully_Convolutional_Networks_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf) paper where they use fully connected upsampling layers. I'm using the contributed `conv3d_transpose` but the concept should be the same as 2D version.

I have an output from a convolutional layer `[6,6,6,256]` being fed into an upsampling layer that is supposed to output `[13,13,13,128]`. Since the layer should be fully connected, the filter should be `[13,13,13,128]` right? (reducing feature map size)

Furthermore, the stride should be `1` correct?

Maybe I am thinking of this backwards, let me explain. The filter defines that size of the *inverted receptive field* (totally made that up) -- the size of the weight matrix *located* on the output layer (thus the full `[13,13,13,128]`). **EDIT INCORRECT [** The strides are the length of strides the *single window* moves on the input image.**] -->**  I now understand that the strides are also in relation to the output layer. For example a filter size 2 with a stride 2, will double the output dimension.
This means that for a fully connected layer, the stride should be `0`, but that isn't possible...

The code for my upsampling is here:

```
temp_batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0] #batch_size shape
with tf.name_scope("deconv6") as scope:
    output_shape = [temp_batch_size, (n_input_z / 4), n_input_x / 4, n_input_y / 4, 128]
    strides = [1,1,1,1,1]
    conv7 = deconv3d(conv6, weights['wdc1'], biases['bdc1'], output_shape, strides, padding=1)
    conv7 = tf.reshape(conv7, [-1, n_input_x / 4, n_input_y / 4, (n_input_z / 4) * 128])
    conv7 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv7)
    conv7 = tf.reshape(conv7, [-1, (n_input_z / 4), n_input_x / 4, n_input_y / 4, 128])
```

The `deconv` function looks like this:

```
def deconv3d(prev_layer, w, b, output_shape, strides, padding=0):
    # Deconv layer
    if padding == 0:
        deconv = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(prev_layer, w, output_shape=output_shape, strides=strides, padding="SAME")
    else:
        deconv = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(prev_layer, w, output_shape=output_shape, strides=strides, padding="VALID")
    deconv = tf.nn.bias_add(deconv, b)
    deconv = tf.nn.relu(deconv)
    return deconv
```

The weights and biases are here:

```
'wdc1' : tf.get_variable("weights_7", shape=[13, 13, 13, 128, 256],
           initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), dtype=tf.float32),
...

'bdc1': tf.Variable(tf.zeros([128], dtype=tf.float32), name="biases_7", dtype=tf.float32),
```

From debugging I can verify input and output dimensions:

```
(Pdb) conv6
<tf.Tensor 'conv5_1/Reshape_1:0' shape=(?, 6, 6, 6, 256) dtype=float32>
(Pdb) output_shape
[<tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, 13, 13, 13, 128]
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Conv3DBackpropInput: Number of planes of out_backprop doesn't match computed:  actual = 6, computed = 1
     [[Node: deconv6/conv3d_transpose = Conv3DBackpropInputV2[T=DT_FLOAT, padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](deconv6/conv3d_transpose/output_shape, weights_7/read, conv5_1/Reshape_1)]]
     [[Node: deconv8/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Shape/_39 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_3797_deconv8/BatchNorm/moments/sufficient_statistics/Shape", tensor_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I assumed from the first `Node` line the problem was in `deconv6`, but I'll post the code if you think it's actually in `deconv8`.

Comment: Did you solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It seems that based on the description from tensorflow official documents, this is not really a deconvolution but a gradient calculation